# Error when building Android Project on Window 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When building for Android I keep having this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class: Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor due to System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Iain Smith\Documents\Developer\Work\Clients\Client1\Project1\Xamarin.Dev.Playground\Source\Client1.Playground.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java'.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Generator.CreateJavaSources(TaskLoggingHelper log, IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, String outputPath, String applicationJavaClass, Boolean useSharedRuntime, Boolean generateOnCreateOverrides, Boolean hasExportReference)    Client1.Playground.Android

What is causing it? How do I fix it? Doesn't seem to happen on the CI builds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a few methods you can use to fix `MAX_PATH` length issues:

**Within a Xamarin.Android .csproj:**

1. `<UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>` - Forces the build process to use shorter path names.
2. `<IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Projects\MyApp</IntermediateOutputPath>` - Specifies a common intermediate output root to make a shorter path.

**Changing the group policy:**

3. Enable Win32 Long Path Support (Supported in Visual Studio 2019+): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

Comment: Oooh I did not know this, some useful bits here!

Comment: I should probably write a blog post on it! :P

Comment: You should @JonDouglas

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Max Path length on Windows, Changed my directory from:

`C:\Users\Iain Smith\Documents\Developer\Work\Clients\Client1\Project1\Xamarin.Dev.Playground\Source\Client1.Playground.Android\`

to:

`C:\Developer\Work\Clients\Client1\Project1\Xamarin.Dev.Playground\Source\Client1.Playground.Android\`

Comment: moving the project/sln directory to a shorter path fixed this for me as well.