# How to fix Xamarin forms build error: “Failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class”

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On build, the compiler is throwing the following error:

Error:-

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class:
>   Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor
>   due to System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of
>   the path
>   'C:\Users\sHaRjAs\source\repos\FormsDatePickerFocusSample\FormsDatePickerFocusSample\FormsDatePickerFocusSample.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java'.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String
>   destination)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Generator.CreateJavaSources(TaskLoggingHelper
>   log, IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, String outputPath, String
>   applicationJavaClass, String androidSdkPlatform, Boolean
>   useSharedRuntime, Boolean generateOnCreateOverrides, Boolean
>   hasExportReference)

XAML Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsDatePickerFocusSample"
             x:Class="FormsDatePickerFocusSample.MainPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     BackgroundColor="White">

        <Button x:Name="MyButton"
                    Text="Show DatePicker"
                    Clicked="OnMyButtonClicked"/>

        <DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker"
                        IsVisible="False"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

c#:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FormsDatePickerFocusSample
{
// Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms 
previewer
// by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void OnMyButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if (MyDatePicker.IsFocused)
                MyDatePicker.Unfocus();

            MyDatePicker.Focus();
        });
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I test with the same code. There is no error. You could try to clean and rebuild this project or delete the bin and obj file data of this project to try again. If you still get this complier error, the quick way is to create a new project to test with the code.

Comment: @WendyZang it's not working (Soln not changed)

Comment: I uploaded my test project on GitHub, you could download to test. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test If you still have errors, could you share more code for me to test?

Comment: Any update? Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Have had a similar error just now. I found that it is connected to my VS solution name beeing kind of descriptive and long

```
WebApp_ReportGenerator_Framework_Dink_Oxy
```

If I created another project with something shorter for a solution and project name (`TestProj`), the android project built with no errors.

@sHaRjAs:
I guess the path to the java files in question (see error description) is too long because your project name is too long. There are also other solutions than project renaming to solve this problem: [Solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184999/error-when-building-android-project-on-window-10) and here [oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/path-too-long-exception).

PS. If in xamarin forms one is using the

`<PropertyGroup>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Projects\MyApp</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>`

solution, note that "MyApp"  folder in upper path is the folder containing all your forms projects : Android,UWP, IOs and standard API projects. This is not clear in the docmentation, I think.

For example if you put in the IntermediateOutputPath property the path to your android project, the Visual Studio locks and needs to be "endTasked".