# error XA5301: Failed to generate Java type for class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Building a xamarin project that comes with a book, I get this error building the project:

> error XA5301: Failed to generate Java type for class:
> Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor
> due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find
> a part of the path '

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The actual project folder path was just too long, shortening that eliminated the problem.

Comment: Thank you for making this answer exist.  I would have been lost.

Comment: How exactly did you resolve this in your project?  Because I elevated the project in my directory to "shorten the path" but that is not working.  Did you change the name of classes such as this one? IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor 

??

Comment: @Krausladen I think it was just project folder was too deep in my documents are something, moving it to some direct folder in C:\ or d:\ drive should fix it.

Comment: You put me on the right path, and I ended up solving it with the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184999/error-when-building-android-project-on-window-10
It's a guaranteed solution.